# When doing an if statement, it always go into false condition when == is given. It will go into true only if != is given

Tags: if-statement

```
h = float(input('Enter Height in meter: '))
w = float(input('Enter your weight in Kg: '))
if h == float and w == float:
    print(f'BMI = ', w / (h ** 2))
else:
    print("Input Error")
```

always going into false condition while float is entered. but if != is given, it will perform correctly. why is that

Comment: What language is this?

Answer (score 0):

if statement should be like this:

```py
if type(h) == float and type(w) == float:
```

and when you try with != code is will always return false because you are trying to match if `5.6 != float` instead you want to try `type(5.6) != float`